# How can you make sure, that an Agent in an Azure Dev Ops Pipeline has firewall access to a storage account?

Tags: azure, ip, terraform, firewall, azure-storage-account

I'm trying to roll out and update an Azure Environment via Terraform azurerm. The .tfstate file for this environment is located in a global storage account so when I run the command 'terraform init' my service principal needs access to that global storage account. In my pipeline I have an extra step to whitelist the IP of the executing Agent in the firewall of the storage account. The command looks like this:

```
az storage account network-rule add -g storage-account-name --account-name rsg-name --ip-address $Build_Agent_IP
sleep 60
az storage account network-rule list -g storage-account-name --account-name rsg-name
```

When I print the network-rules for that storage account, the IP of the running Agent is always listed there. The problem now is, that sometimes (maybe 50% of the time) my following 'terraform init' command failes, because of an Authorization failure caused by the firewall settings. My guess is that the firewall settings aren't updated properly at the time I run 'terraform init'. Is there a way to make sure that the executing agent has access to the storage account?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to make sure that the executing agent has access to the
> storage account?

We can run storage account show command to determine if the access to the storage account is restricted to specific (trusted) IP addresses/IP address ranges.

```
az storage account show
    --name xxx
    --query 'networkRuleSet.ipRules[?(action==`Allow`)].ipAddressOrRange'
```

The command output should return the list with all the IPv4 addresses allowed to access your storage account. Compare the IPs list returned by the storage account show command output with the IP of the executing Agent to see if they are consistent.

For details, you can refer to this [link](https://www.cloudconformity.com/knowledge-base/azure/StorageAccounts/limit-access-by-ip-address.html).

Answer (score -1):

Quick update to my question. The code shown in my example works perfectly fine and the public IP of the agent is whitelisted in the firewall of the storage account (also at the time executing 'terraform init'). So there shouldn't be a problem with the agent accessing the storage account. The problem is that sometimes (my described 50% of the time) the agent doesn't access the storage account with its public IP address but with some different IP address. In my case this was for example 10.1.0.4. So of course this IP isn't whitelisted an the agent can't access the storage account. Where this IP comes from and why this only happens sometimes I still don't know.

Comment: this is not an answer